# How to solve the integral $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} i (k^2 + a)^{1/2} e^{ikx} dk$

Tags: definite-integrals

How to solve the following integral?

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} i (k^2 + a)^{1/2} e^{ikx} dk$$

and some literature on this, thanks.

Comment: Any thoughts, please try to write, **if any**.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3827524/168433

Comment: This integral gives one primitive function to the one in https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3827524/168433 (modulo a factor $i$).

Comment: I know that the derivative of this function is the function that is in the link that you put, but I can't see how it affects the Bessel function,  I am not clear about it, please help

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $a > 0$ and let $a = b^2$ with the understanding that $b > 0$.

Denote the integral in question

$$ I(b,x) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} i (k^2 + b^2)^{1/2} e^{ikx} dk
$$
We have
$$\frac{\partial I(b,x)}{\partial b} ={i b} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(k^2 + b^2)^{1/2}} e^{ikx} dk$$
Now it has been shown [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3827524/how-to-integrate-int-infty-infty-fraci-kk2-a1-2-eikx-dk) that
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}dk\frac{e^{ikx}}{\sqrt{k^2+b^2}} = 2K_0(b x)$$

where $K_0(x)$ is a modified Bessel function. So we have
$$\frac{\partial I(b,x)}{\partial b} =2 i b K_0(b x)$$

Now treat $x$ as a constant and substitute $b \to bx = c$ to get

$$\frac{\partial I(c,x)}{\partial c} =\frac{2 i}{x^2} c K_0(c)$$

We recover
$$
I(c,x) = \int \frac{\partial I(c,x)}{\partial c} dc =\frac{2 i}{x^2}\int    c K_0(c) dc 
= \frac{2 i}{x^2} (-c K_1 (c))$$
with $K_1(c)$ again a modified Bessel function.

Resubstituting $c = bx$ gives the result

$$
I(b,x)
= - \frac{2 i b}{x} K_1 (b x)$$

Comment: Thank you very much. The substitution of b for bx = c did not occur to me. Now I will study more to Bessel functions. Thank you again!

Comment: Same as in the linked answer, it's not true that $\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{i x k}/\sqrt {k^2 + b^2} \, dk = 2 K_0(b x)$ for all $b > 0$ and $x \in \mathbb R \setminus \{ 0 \}$, and $\int_{-\infty}^\infty \sqrt {k^2 + b^2} \, e^{i x k} dk$ diverges if understood as an improper integral (or even as a p.v. integral).